# How do you compute the metric tensor for this metric formula?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to derive the metric tensor for a complex manifold with uniform acceleration in four dimensions. I have a metric formula that works well, but am having trouble computing the infinitesimals. The model of expansion is:

[image]

Where $\Delta\sigma$ is the proper space displacement and $\Delta\tau$ is the proper time displacement and $\Delta x^r$ is the coordinate space displacement and $\Delta x^t$ is the coordinate time displacement.  The metric formula is:$$\Delta s^2=-\frac{1}{4}\left(\tau_0-\tau_1 \right)^2\left(-2V + A\left(\tau_0+\tau_1 \right) \right)^2+\frac{\left(-2V\left(t_0+t_1 \right) + A\left(\tau_0^2+\tau_1^2 \right)\right)^2}{4 \tau_1^2\left(-2V+A\tau_1\right)}\left(\Delta x^r \right)^2$$
Where $A$ and $V$ are constants.

I understand the basic concept of taking the derivative with respect to each of the dimensions, but I'm having trouble coming up with the exact steps. The main problem for me seems to be that the spatial term has two displacements in it, $\Delta x^r$ and $\Delta \tau=\tau_1-\tau_0$ that I want to turn into infinitesimals.

Also, I know what the answer is. Integrating this formula from $\tau_0$ to $\tau_1$ using infinitesimals gives the same results as the metric formula above using displacements.$$ds^2=-(V-A\tau)^2(dx^t)^2+\frac{1}{4}(dx^r)^2$$So, my question is: **given $\boldsymbol{\Delta s}$, how would one find $\boldsymbol{ds}$**?

Comment: I *think* (IIUC) what you want is divide by $(\Delta\tau)^2$ and take limit $\Delta s/\Delta\tau\to ds/d\tau$, etc. and so you have $ds^2$.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the operation "$\Delta s/\Delta \tau\rightarrow ds/d\tau$". I understand how to take the limit of one of those variables as it approaches another variable, but I don't know how to take the limit of a ratio as it approaches another ratio. Could you be a little more explicit with that last step, please?

Comment: I mean as $\Delta\tau\to 0$ you get $\Delta s/\Delta\tau\to ds/d\tau$ and similarly $\Delta x^\bullet/\Delta\tau\to dx^\bullet/d\tau$ where $\bullet=r,t$.

Comment: Trying to turn your suggestion into Mathematica code, so bear with me. How, exactly, are you defining $\Delta\tau$? Are you speaking generically of the temporal term, or are you specifically introducing a new variable $\Delta\tau=\tau_1-\tau_0$?

Comment: $\Delta\tau$ is defined in your diagram as $\tau_1-\tau_0$, no?